# Elm: How does this init work?

Tags: elm

```
type alias Model =
  { dieFace : Int
  }


init : (Model, Cmd Msg)
init =
  (Model 1, Cmd.none)
```

Why does the integer `1` get passed to the model ala `Model 1`?

The type alias seems to requiring a record?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is not so much un-explained magic in Elm (for good reason), but one bit is the type and type alias constructors. Whenever you create a type (alias) you get a constructor function for free. So, to use your example,

```
type alias Model =
  { dieFace : Int
  }
```

gives you a (somewhat weird-looking) constructor function

```
Model : Int -> Model
```

for free. If you add more entries to your record, like this

```
type alias Model =
  { dieFace : Int
  , somethingElse : String
  }
```

the constructor function takes more arguments.

```
Model : Int -> String -> Model
```

The order of these are the same order as the record entries, so if you change the order of your type aliases, you'll have to change the argument order to to the constructor function.

Union types work in a similar way.

```
type Shape
  = Circle Int
  | Square Int Int
```

quietly creates constructors:

```
Circle: Int -> Shape 
Square : Int -> Int -> Shape
```

Answer (score 3):

In `Model 1` "Model" is used as positional record constructor. It is equal to `{dieFace = 1}`

---

Here is another example:

```
type alias Rcd =
    { first : String
    , second : Int 
    }
```

Rcd can be constructed in two ways:

```
Rcd "some string" 4
{ first = "some string" , second = 4}
```

The former variant is just shorthand and often used for initialisation of Records.

Comment: So I'll just confirm, that would imply that records guarantee the order of their data, unlike objects in javascript?

Comment: Yes they do when you use the constructor - if you use the {} notation for construction the order doesn't matter. The order is also relevant when you pattern match records (e.g. in case statements or function attributes).